# Installer entry is not available in Add/Remove Programs in Wix

Tags: wix

I am using wix to create installer. I am using below code in Product.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="{98356803-6759-78F5-458F-378295D23DAF}" Name="Test Install" UpgradeCode="{345D4770-545D-4A53-BA07-EF52401F0CB4}" Language="1033" Version="1.1.1.1" Manufacturer="Installer. Inc">
    <Package Description="Sample Installer" Comments="Test Install" Manufacturer="Installer. Inc" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
```

I am using below properties.

```
    <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
    <Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="1" />
    <Property Id="ARPNOREMOVE" Value="1" />
    <Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1" />
```

But My installer entry is not availble in Programs and Features (Windows 7). Is there anything I missed? Please let me know any other details you need. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not there because you set the [ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to 1.

Per MSDN setting this property:

> Setting the **ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT** property to 1 using the command line or
>   a transform prevents the application from being displayed in the **Add
>   or Remove Programs list** of **Control Panel**.